# How to implement object from other one

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, vue-component

I'm learning Javascript by myself. I work with Vuejs & express on a CRUD App.

On a component, I request my back-end trough my api : localhost:3000/api/transport
Response give me all objects from the db.

With this response I want to implement an object to make a calendar using [`vue-val`](https://antoniandre.github.io/vue-cal/#api) component.

This is my component script :

```
<script>
import VueCal from 'vue-cal'
import 'vue-cal/dist/vuecal.css'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  components: { VueCal },
  data() {
    return {
      transport: [],
      events: [
        /*{ 
          start: '2021-01-21 10:30',
          end: '2021-01-21 11:30',
          title: 'Rdv dentiste',
          content: '<i class="v-icon material-icons">local_hospital</i>',
          class: 'health'
        },*/
      ],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getTransport();
  },
  methods: {
    getTransport: function() {
        this.loading = true;
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/transport/')
            .then((response) => {
                this.transport = response.data;
                this.implementEvents(this.transport);
                this.loading = false;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                this.loading = false;
                console.log(err);
        })
    },
    implementEvents: function(transports) {
      for(var transport in transports) {
        console.log(transport.id)
        this.events.push({
          start: transport.startDate,
          end: transport.endDate,
          title: transporte.designation
        })
      }
    }
    }
};
</script>
```

`implementEvents` function take my response on parameter but I don't know why don't implement events array.

If I replace with code below, it's work.

```
implementEvents: function(transports) {
      for(var transport in transports) {
        console.log(transport.id)
        this.events.push({
          start: '2021-01-21 10:30',
          end: '2021-01-21 10:30',
          title: 'test'
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: does the console.log statement output as expected?

Comment: No. On the console, I just have "9 undefined". 9 corresponds to the number of entries on the database

Comment: the argument "transports"...is that an array of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using forEach instead of for-in

```
implementEvents: function(transports) {
        trnsports.forEach(transport => {
        console.log(transport.id)
        this.events.push({
          start: transport.startDate,
          end: transport.endDate,
          title: transporte.designation
        })
       })
    }
```